# Why is "margin-top" property of a static element is affecting the "top" property of an absolute element?

Tags: html, css

Currently I am developing a PSD design for a project, and in that design a section has a completely different kind of a shape for appealing appearance.

To create that shape I have created an svg file and used it as background and positioned that section by the absolute property. After this absolute positioned section there is another section, which needs to be after the absolute one.

To align this static section I tried to use "margin-top" property. Now the problem arises. The margin-top property is affecting the "top" property of the absolute positioned section. The margin property is also moving the absolute positioned elements position along with t

This is the problem which is confusing me completely, and I am unable to find a solution for this.

I have shared a sample design below which depicts the problem.

I hope that I will get a positive response regarding this query. Apart from this improvement advises regarding the design development will also be appreciated.

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
   
#main-container{
   position: relative;
}
   
#section-1{
   background-color: #e48b21;
   height: 500px;
}
   
#section-2{
   height: 1000px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   position: absolute;
   top: 70%;
}
   
#section-2 p{
   margin-top: 10%;
}
   
#section-3{
   background-color: #808080;
   margin-top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test 101</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="main-container">
   
   <div id="section-1">
    <p>Some Text</p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="section-2">
    <p>Some Text</p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="section-3">
    <p>Some Text</p>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @giorgio's answer should clarify your question. However, What effect are you actually looking for? Maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: I just want to bring the section-2 in front of section-1 and section-3 beneath section 2. Section-2 has a background-image which is a shape and which is being used to make the webpage look more appealing.

Comment: you are already giving heights to sections so you don't need percentage values for positions. You can just use the pixel values. Hope this might help you a bit.

Comment: @giorgrio answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the static element is affecting the height of the parent, and your absolutely positioned element is positioned by percentage.

Your `#section-2` has a `top` value of `70%`. That means; the top of this element will be at `70%` height of the parent (eg; the parent is `100px` high, then the top of this element will be at `70px`). Now, because you have a top margin on your static element, it will stretch the parent (only when it's high enough of course), meaning `70%` will be a higher value when calculated.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help buddy.